Impossible to do a migration with ADO using multiple appSettings
I did a pipeline and a release on ADO for my API and I want to do a migration between server.
So there is the yaml on my task :
variables:
  ArtifactsDropFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)\drop'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet ef database update'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: exec
    arguments: '--runtimeconfig Api\ProjectInformation.Back.runtimeconfig.json --depsfile Api\ProjectInformation.Back.deps.json ef.dll database update --assembly Data\ProjectInformation.Back.Data.dll --startup-assembly Api\ProjectInformation.Back.dll --context ProjectInformationDbContext --verbose --working-dir  "$(ArtifactsDropFolder)\ef"'
    workingDirectory: '$(ArtifactsDropFolder)\ef'

But when it comes to the task, I have te following error :
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

In my program.cs, I have the following line :
var template = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectionStringTemplate"];
var sqlInstanceName = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:SqlInstanceName"];
var databaseName = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:DatabaseName"];

template = template.FormatWith(sqlInstanceName, databaseName);

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProjectInformationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(template);
});

Following the Microsoft documentation, I didn't add the :
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

Since it's not necessary in .NET8.
I have 3 appsettings : Development, Validation and Production and the appsettings.json
All my appSettings are presents in the deploiement folder.
the appsettings.json looks like this :
"AppSettings": {
  "ConnectionStringTemplate": "Data Source={0};DataBase={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
},

Others appsettings looks like this :
"AppSettings": {
  "SqlInstanceName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "DatabaseName": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
},

If I put some Console.WriteLine(), all the value ConnectionStringTemplate, SqlInstanceName and DatabaseName are null. It looks like files are not correctly upload on the server.
If I put directly the connection string in the DbContext (options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=XXX;DataBase=XXX;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;")), it works perfectly.
I tried everything I found on the Internet, did someone have and idea on this problem ?

When you run the same dotnet command on your local machine, will the appsettings be replaced with the expected value? Have you set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable in Azure Pipeline? If you haven't set the variable, it may not find the correct settings file to update the appsettings.json file.
